# Remove and Identify Duplicate Records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have some sample records below that I need to use the CASE WHEN statement to remove and identify the duplicate records in SQL.

```
Quantity    Values      Desc    event   ID
1               5       Blue    12550   577
1               5       bluee   12550   525
2               10      blu     12550   535
```

i would like to use a case statement to show the duplicate indicators such as:

```
Dup_Quantity    Dup_Value   Dup_Desc  Quantity  Values   Desc   event   ID
Y       Y       N     1     5    Blue   12550   577
Y       Y       N     1     5    Bluee  12550   525
```

however, after using this script, the result still shows as:

```
Dup_Quantity    Dup_Value   Dup_Desc  Quantity  Values   Desc   event   ID
Y       Y       N     1     5    Blue   12550   577
Y       Y       N     1     5    Bluee  12550   525 
Y       N       N     2     10   Blu    12550   535


SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN a.Quantity = b.Quantity THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Dup_Quantity",
    CASE WHEN a.Values = b.Values THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Dup_Value",
    CASE WHEN a.Desc = b.Desc THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Dup_Desc"
FROM Table1 a 
INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.event = b.event 
WHERE (a.Quantity = b.Quantity OR a.Values = b.Values OR a.Desc = b.Desc)
    AND a.ID <> b.ID
```

Basically, record with ID 535 stills shows up in the result. Would someone Please give me some pointers?

Comment: what kind of BD are using? That statement can't even return all that rows

Comment: it is run in SQL sever2012

Comment: Why do you think ID 535 shouldn't appear? I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Basically you are joining a table with itself based on Event field. You have 3 records: They all vary on description, quantity or value, so there are no duplicates as long as i can see.

Comment: I don't ID535 returned in my result. I am trying display the two records (id 577 and 525) with three new fields in the front with Yes or No. Record ID535 did not meet my criteria and that is why it is still returning. I know the issue is on my script but could not figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff711/20)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Quantity] int, [Values] int, [Desc] varchar(5), [event] int, [ID] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Quantity], [Values], [Desc], [event], [ID])
VALUES
    (1, 5, 'Blue', 12550, 577),
    (1, 5, 'bluee', 12550, 525),
    (2, 10, 'blu', 12550, 535)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Table1 t2 
           WHERE t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity AND 
                  t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.event = t2.event) > 0
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Dup_Quantity,
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Table1 t2 
           WHERE t1."Values" = t2."Values" AND 
                  t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.event = t2.event) > 0
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Dup_Value,
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Table1 t2 
           WHERE t1."Desc" = t2."Desc" AND 
                  t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.event = t2.event) > 0
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Dup_Desc,
*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Table1 t2 
           WHERE t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity AND 
                 t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.event = t2.event) > 0
OR
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Table1 t2 
           WHERE t1."Values" = t2."Values" AND 
                 t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.event = t2.event) > 0
OR
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Table1 t2 
           WHERE t1."Desc" = t2."Desc" AND 
                 t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.event = t2.event) > 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ff711/20/0)**:

```
| DUP_QUANTITY | DUP_VALUE | DUP_DESC | QUANTITY | VALUES |  DESC | EVENT |  ID |
|--------------|-----------|----------|----------|--------|-------|-------|-----|
|            Y |         Y |        N |        1 |      5 |  Blue | 12550 | 577 |
|            Y |         Y |        N |        1 |      5 | bluee | 12550 | 525 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns:

```
Dup_Quantity    Dup_Value   Dup_Desc
     Y              Y          N
```

However I don't get what you want to do here, the correct version of it is:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a."Quantity" = b."Quantity" THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Dup_Quantity",
    CASE WHEN a."Values" = b."Values" THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Dup_Value",
    CASE WHEN a."Desc" = b."Desc" THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Dup_Desc",
    a.*
FROM Table1 a 
INNER JOIN Table1 b  ON b.event = a.event 
WHERE (a."Quantity" = b."Quantity" OR a."Values" = b."Values" OR a."Desc" = b."Desc")
    AND a.ID <> b.ID
```

If you want to get duplicated rows in terms of `Quantity`, `Values` and `Desc`:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM Table1 a 
INNER JOIN Table1 b  ON b.event = a.event 
WHERE (a."Quantity" = b."Quantity" AND a."Values" = b."Values" AND a."Desc" = b."Desc")
    AND a.ID <> b.ID
```

Comment: @answered31 - I would like to show the potential duplicate records in (Dup_Quantity, Dup_Value, Dup_Desc) field. Basically, the purpose of these three fields is to quickly able to tell are they the same in quantity, values, and desc. Thanks for your quick response!